# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row in Update Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, for-loop, sql-update

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row in update statement

Hi. For below query, ORA-01427 error occurred.

I'm trying to get birthday from country_population and set it as fave_date in city_population. Other simpler way to execute this is not needed, I just need some suggestion how to eliminate the error and let the query work.
Thank you :)

```
    DECLARE
            CURSOR custCur IS
                     SELECT name, age, weight, height, birthday FROM country_population;
            CNTR number(9) := 0;
    BEGIN
            FOR curRec IN custCur LOOP

                    UPDATE city_population srvagr
                    SET     srvagr.date1 = SYSDATE,
                            srvagr.fave_date =
                                            (select curRec.birthday from country_population curRec
                                            where srvagr.name=curRec.name
                                            and srvagr.age=curRec.age
                                            and srvagr.weight=curRec.weight
                                            and srvagr.height=curRec.height),
                            srvagr.date2 = SYSDATE,
                            srvagr.date3 = SYSDATE,
                            srvagr.status = 'visitor',
                            srvagr.note = 'Noted'
                    WHERE
                            srvagr.name = curRec.name
                            and srvagr.age = curRec.age
                            and srvagr.weight = curRec.weight
                            and srvagr.height = curRec.height
                            and srvagr.status != 'visitor'
                            and srvagr.fave_date is null;

                    CNTR := CNTR + 1;
                    if CNTR = 1000
                            then
                                    COMMIT;
                                    CNTR := 0;
                    end if;

            END LOOP;

            COMMIT;
```

Comment: The error is relatively clear, the sub-query is returning more than 1 row for the criteria supplied - either you need to refine those criteria more, or in the event of multiple rows make an aggregate decision about what to choose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the query

```
(select curRec.birthday from country_population curRec
                      where srvagr.name=curRec.name
                      and srvagr.age=curRec.age
                      and srvagr.weight=curRec.weight
                      and srvagr.height=curRec.height)
```

return   more than a row so you can't use with a equal assigment  ..

in this case you could add  more selective where condition for get only a row result

or if there si not one result only anyway  use an aggregation function  for reduce the result eg: min() or max()

```
(select min(curRec.birthday)  from country_population curRec
                      where srvagr.name=curRec.name
                      and srvagr.age=curRec.age
                      and srvagr.weight=curRec.weight
                      and srvagr.height=curRec.height
                      )
```

or use limit for rows result

```
(select min(curRec.birthday)  from country_population curRec
                      where srvagr.name=curRec.name
                      and srvagr.age=curRec.age
                      and srvagr.weight=curRec.weight
                      and srvagr.height=curRec.height
                      and rownum = 1)
```

Comment: How will I identify if min() and/or rownum=1 return the correct birthday? Actually, with the 4 conditions in where clause, I am expecting that only 1 birthday is assigned to 1 name/age/height/weight (wherein name is unique per row).

Comment: explain better you comment .. is not clear .. .. you shoudl know the criteria for return the right value and you should choose the proper query between the several proposed

Comment: i mean, if the subquery returns many rows (e.g. Jan1, Feb1, Mar1), what is the assurance that correct value will be retrieved for each name/age/height/weight?
will it be based on where clause of the update statement?

Comment: the value you are processing is where subquery are the same  of the value you are processing in where for update  .. this a DB engine responsability ..

Comment: Hi @ scaisEdge - your suggestion worked. thank you :)